# what does "git pull remotename -u remotebranchname" do?

Tags: git

what does -u option with pull do?

my current branch is master.

does it pull from remote branch to my current branch(master)?

is this command pulling from specified "remote branch" into my current(master) branch?
what is the affect of running this git command?

actually i used a set of commands and ended up polluting my feature branch so trying to track which command did it.

whether executing this command gets changes from specified remote branch into my current branch(master)?

Comment: Could you highlight what point in the documentation (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) was unclear?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier -in man page i dint get what was explained for -u.now i got somewhat idea about it.thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal use of git, this option has no effect.

The documentation explains that it is the short form of the `--update-head-ok` option. This option is used to allow a fetch to change the branch you're currently on. So if your branch is master, this option allows a fetch to change `refs/heads/master`.

When you use git normally, you won't be doing that. The fetch will only change `refs/remotes/origin/master`. It's the subsequent merge that updates `refs/heads/master`. The `-u` option does not change how that merge works.

Given that the effect of this option is to disable a sanity check, you shouldn't be using it, unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages for `git pull`

```
-u, --update-head-ok
           By default git-fetch refuses to update the head which corresponds to the current branch. This flag disables the check. This is purely for the internal
           use for git-pull to communicate with git-fetch, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not supposed to use it.
```